# RabbitMQ users + how to create user for rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

we get the following when we want to see rabbitmq users

```
rabbitmqctl list_users
Listing users ...
guest   [administrator]
...done.
```

now we want to add user airflow ( create user )

what is the right approach to add user ?

expected output

```
rabbitmqctl list_users
Listing users ...
airflow []
guest   [administrator]
...done.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with ’add_user’. See the command man page https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html